# Prevent delaying due to debouncing on search bar

Tags: reactjs, lodash, debouncing

I have a search bar, in which I fetch the typed text and make an API call. To limit the number of API calls, I am using debouncing. I want to show a loader the moment something is typed in the search bar, but due to debouncing that operation is also delayed. I tried to replicate the behaviour in below code-

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./style.css";
import { debounce } from "lodash";

export default function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const callAPI = () => {
    setLoading(true);


    // Post this will be the logic to call API
    console.log('API is called')
  };
  const inputChangeHandler = event => {
    const text = event.target.value;
    if (text.length === 0) {
      setLoading(false);
    } else {
      callAPI();
    }
  };
  const debouncedChangeHandler = debounce(inputChangeHandler, 1000);

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={debouncedChangeHandler} />
      {loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mxeek4?file=src%2FApp.js) is the link

I want to show a loader the moment something is typed in the search bar but I also want to debounce the invoking of API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `{ leading: true }` option when creating the [debounced](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce) function:

```
const debouncedChangeHandler = debounce(inputChangeHandler, 1000, { leading: true });
```

This would cause the 1st call (the leading edge to invoke the function immediately, and debounce the rest.

Example:

```js
const { useState } = React;
const { debounce } = _;

function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const callAPI = () => {
    setLoading(true);

    // Post this will be the logic to call API
    console.log("API is called");
  };
  const inputChangeHandler = event => {
    const text = event.target.value;
    if (text.length === 0) {
      setLoading(false);
    } else {
      callAPI();
    }
  };
  
  const debouncedChangeHandler = debounce(inputChangeHandler, 1000, { leading: true });

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={debouncedChangeHandler} />
      {loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Or you can debounce only the `callAPI` function:

```js
const { useState } = React;
const { debounce } = _;

function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const callAPI = () => {
    // Post this will be the logic to call API
    console.log("API is called");
  };
  
  const debouncedCallAPI = debounce(callAPI, 1000);
  
  const inputChangeHandler = event => {
    const text = event.target.value;
    if (text.length === 0) {
      setLoading(false);
    } else {
      setLoading(true);
      debouncedCallAPI();
    }
  };
 

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={inputChangeHandler} />
      {loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: But without { leading: true }, fewer times API call is made as compared to with it.

Comment: Leading has at least 1 more call at the state. Another option it to debounce just the `callAPI` function. See updated answer.